# Symfony assets on localhost (Wamp)

Tags: css, symfony, vhosts

I am running symfony on my localhost for learn, i have configured my localhost folder http://localhost/symfony to http:/symfonyweb.

Everything works fine but style can't loading,

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/style.css">`

full url is: `http://symfonyweb/assets/css/style.css`

Comment: First, make sure your symfony/web/assets/css/style.css really exists

Comment: Yes is it in the web folder and i have used following code: `{% block stylesheets %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('assets/css/style.css') }}">
        {% endblock %}`

Comment: Any other ways?

Answer (score 0):

Your asset should be load using the function `asset()` which is linked to `/web` root directory.

In your case, your assets should be like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('assets/css/style.css') }}">`

Comment: Its already there but not loading here is my base.htm.twig code:
`{% block stylesheets %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('assets/css/style.css') }}">
        {% endblock %}`

Comment: Any other ways?